# MongoCollection: auto-increment OR insert if not present

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi all I using the following query in Mongo shell to create or increment a value as seen below

```
db.collection.update({"_id": ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXX")}, {"$inc": {"analytics.clicks": 1 }})
```

but when replicating this in php it does not set a key value if it is not available.

```
$collection->update(array("_id" => $realmongoid), array('$inc' => array("analytics.clicks" => 1)));
```

Is there another function I should be using in php to force create key value if it is not available.

Any help would be great.

Comment: maybe changed this as `"_id" => new MongoId($realmongoid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `array("upsert" => true)` option. More info in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php).

```
$collection->update(
  array("_id" => $realmongoid), 
  array('$inc' => array("analytics.clicks" => 1)), 
  array("upsert" => true)
);
```